# How to use Test-Path in SharePoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Using the `Test-Path` PowerShell command we can check if the system drive path or file exists or not in local drive. Similarly how can we check if the SharePoint document library folder path or file in document library exists or not using `Test-Path` or any similar command?

```
Test-Path -Path "http://win-3:001/sites/Dev/Shared%20Documents/Test1"
Test-Path -Path "http://win-3:001/sites/Dev/Shared%20Documents/Test1/sample.txt"
```

Comment: Can this script be run from one of the SharePoint web servers?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check that with an HTTP request:

```
$uri = 'http://win-3:001/sites/Dev/Shared%20Documents/Test1'

(Invoke-WebRequest -Method Head -Uri $uri -UseDefaultCredentials).StatusCode
```

If your PowerShell version is too old to provide the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet you should upgrade. If for some reason you can't do that use the [`System.Net.WebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class instead:

```
$uri = 'http://win-3:001/sites/Dev/Shared%20Documents/Test1'

$req = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
$req.Method = 'HEAD'
$req.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$req.PreAuthenticate = $true
$req.Credentials = [Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
$req.GetResponse().StatusCode.value__
```

Either way, a status code of 200 means the request was OK, i.e. the document exists.

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest is not recognized command geeting error. m running in sharepoint 2010 server.

Comment: Getting Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Comment: And you couldn't be bothered to look that up yourself?

Comment: I have tested this code its working fine in folder level, but for file level is not working..even though file exists in the given path says does not exist.